# converting a varchar to datetime in sql server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, converters, varchar

I have a varchar `20130909132512` and I would like to convert it into just a date `2013-09-09`

I keep getting an error when trying

```
select convert(datetime,'20130909132512',105)
```

and I am trying to avoid using

```
select convert(datetime,SUBSTRING('20130909132512',0,8),105)
```

if possible. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you use bummi's `STUFF` method or continue using `SUBSTRING`, you're going to have to pre-format the string no matter what you do.

In this case, `SUBSTRING` will perform a bit faster

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, SUBSTRING('20130909132512', 0, 9), 20)
```

You'll want to use "20" as the conversion style, though, if you want the date in the format 2013-09-09.

Comment: That's what I thought. Wasn't sure if it would be able to read the format. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could transform your varchar to **20130909 13:25:12** using [STUFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

```
Declare @a Varchar(20)
Select @a = '20130909132512'
select convert(datetime,
              STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@a,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' ')
              ,105)
```